# Is it possible to use applets in C++

Tags: c++, netbeans-7

I am trying to create a game in traveling salesman problem using iterative algorithm.

I need the output in an applet environment, in a new window.

Is it possible to use applets in C++ like we normally use it in Java platform?

Can anyone clear my doubt?

Comment: Are you interviewing yourself?

Comment: @larsmans, i am in need of help from you friend.

Comment: Use Winforms in C#, if you know C++ it may look a bit familiar. Else you may need some messaging to make the data flow from C++ to Java.

Comment: @DumbCoder, but is there any packages related to applets are available for netbeans in C++, if it is there, i don't find anything on web. Is any specific header files for C++ applets.

Comment: Disagree with close vote. "Java Applets" are well-defined (see e.g. `java.applet.Applet`), and it's reasonable to wonder if there's an equivalent in C++.

Answer (score 1):

No. Java applets compile to Java bytecode and are delivered to a JVM running in a webbrowser. C++ programs (currently) cannot be compiled to Java bytecode, so they cannot be shipped to webbrowsers. Google is doing some work in this area (Native Client, NaCl) but that's far from finished.

Comment: In terms of a C++ web application the only way I can think to do it is to write a backend engine in C++ and use that engine to fire AJAX messages to your host server/client. You could also have a downloadable engine for your clients to run on their machines and fire AJAX at a JS+HTML frontend. You would need a C++ server capable of accepting AJAX requests and replying though.
You are probably better off writing the whole thing in ECMAScript (javascript) IMO... or Flash/Silverlight...

Comment: Well, I've written a "C++ web application" with a CGI interface. Back in 1997 or so, but you could still do so today ;)

Comment: You could but it's not entirely suitable for a game though. Unless it was a text adventure... :)